# Translation of 'ekayano maggo'

Tags: vipassana, terminology

In the Mahasatipatthana (DN 22) sutra the Buddha speaks about **ekayano maggo**. What is the exact translation in English: is it: *'direct way'* or *'only way'*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following are some interpretations any translation should consider:

- This is the way does not branch off (Direct way, single way)
- This is the way as taught by the Buddha (The way of the One)
- This is the way that one should practice alone. Any body else practice will not help.
- This is the way leading to one destination
- This is the only way leading to the destination. There is no other way.

(Source: The Four Foundations of Mindfulness by Sayadaw U Silananda)

The best translation may be **"the way"**

Answer (score 4):

The [analysis quoted here](http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=3539#p51511) says that, literally, it could be either; but that, looking at various places in which it's used in context, it makes more sense if it means 'direct'.
The people on that site seemed to agree that that's the best analysis.

And, [this article](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/voc/ekayanomaggo.html) makes a similar argument to explain why 'direct' is a more fitting meaning than 'only'.

Comment: "Direct" would make more sense than "only" because there are many other meditation methods prescribed by the Buddha and bodhisattvas which he also said lead to cessation. But then again "direct" isn't totally accurate either..

Comment: Chris, the argument in the mentioned 'article' makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding "Ekayano Maggo" means "sure path" or  in Sinhala "Ekanthayenma ya haki Margayak"